# Testing Rectagles Intersection on CGRect's

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

I am trying to detect collision between sprites from the same NSMutableArray. I am running a loop to compare one sprite with all of them, inclusing itself.

The thing is that the "CGRectEqualToRect" method is returning me a TRUE boolean, even though it is not!

```
- (BOOL)detectCollision: (CCSprite*)sprite{

BOOL result = FALSE;

CCSprite *toCollide;
CGRect rect1 = [GameScene positionRect:sprite];

for (int i = 0; i < [movableSprites count]; i++){

    toCollide = [movableSprites objectAtIndex:i];
    CGRect rect2 = [GameScene positionRect:toCollide];

    if (!CGRectIsNull(CGRectIntersection(rect1, rect2))) {
        if(!CGRectEqualToRect(rect1, rect2)){

          //handle collision
          NSLog(@"Collides");
          result = TRUE;
        }
    }

}

return result;
```

}

For instance, when debugging, rect1 is returning the same sizes as rect2, but its x and y are completely different.

Any ideas on this one?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out this ..[LINK](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/sprite-collision-detection/)

Comment: Yeah.. I tried that link. Used "- (CGRect)makeRect:(Sprite *)mySprite" instead of "positionRect". But it still passes my check and always triggers the collision. Origin is different but Size is the same. And I am not scaling them ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
   - (BOOL)detectCollision: (CCSprite*)sprite
    {
        BOOL result = FALSE;

        for (int i = 0; i < [movableSprites count]; i++)
        {
            CCSprite *toCollide; = [movableSprites objectAtIndex:i];
            if(sprite==toCollide){
                continue;
            }
            if (CGRectIntersectsRect(sprite.boundingBox, toCollide.boundingBox)) {

                //handle collision
                NSLog(@"Collides");
                result = TRUE;
                return result;
            }

        }
      return result;
    }
```

Make sure that all sprites are added to same object(Parent),otherwise you same to do some changes..

Comment: Pretty much the same. I just moved the "return result;" to the next bracket. The "sprite==toCollide" works. But at least once on every loop the CGRectIntersectsRect is triggered to collision.

Comment: All the objects are created at the same time to the same object.Like this:         for(int i = 0; i < images.count; ++i) {
            NSString *image = [images objectAtIndex:0];
            CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:image];
            sprite.position = ccp(AREA_A1_X1 + (i * 56), AREA_A1A6A2_Y);
            [self addChild:sprite];
            [movableSprites addObject:sprite];
        }

Comment: Oh..that one is my mistake.Can give some log where condition are not met(bounding box).Is seems like nothing wrong in these lines.

Comment: Hi Vivek! I have edited your post just so you can see the log. Couldn't post here as a comment.

Comment: every thing works fine...in second case it collide...and that fine
Sprite X=599 Collide Sprite=656 ....(656-599)<Sprite's Width i.e 64. What is problem, i doesn't understand

Comment: You're right! The thing here is that the PNG image was bigger than its own content. Too much transparency material. Thanks!